# Shortcut or Terminal Command to toggle Chrome Hardware Acceleration on/off

Tags: macos, google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, terminal

I'm trying to figure out how to create a shortcut or a terminal command for on/off Hardware Acceleration in Advanced settings of Chrome Browser on a Mac.

Has anyone done this already or know how to?

I'm looking for the simplest way to make this change on multiple Macbooks in my district.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a large list of available command-line switches for Google Chrome.  http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/
You may need to combine some to get the desired acceleration.